# Is there a difference between importing scanner before the class or in the main class

Tags: java, import, java.util.scanner

Is there a difference between importing Scanner like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

and doing this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only difference is the scope and the syntax.

Comment: (In terms of speed)

Comment: If the bytecodes are identical, than the two codes are completely equivalent.

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate. In the future, please consider searching for duplicate questions before asking, thus avoiding posting an unnecessary duplicate and having your question closed. For example a search like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+import+vs+full+package+name+site:stackoverflow.com) (click on the link) would work well in your situation.

Comment: Look at the canonical question and its possible duplicate - **there is no difference** in terms of performance.

Comment: Imports are a merely syntactic convenience, so you don't have to use the fully-qualified name everywhere. There is no difference after compilation.